# How do I render multiple React classes into one root node?

Tags: reactjs

I am creating a website using React. I realized after building, it only displayed the  and  components.

This is how my App.js looks like:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Header from './components/Header/Header';
import Footer from './components/Footer/Footer';
import Home from './components/Home/Home';
import About from './components/About/About';
import Team from './components/Team/Team';
import Projects from './components/Projects/Projects';
import Contact from './components/Contact/Contact';
import Documents from './components/Documents/Documents';
import FAQ from './components/FAQ/FAQ';
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';

class App extends Component {

  render() {
      return (
        <div>
          <Header />
            <Route exact={true} path="/" component={Home} />
            <Route path="/about" component={About} />
            <Route path="/projects" component={Projects} />
            <Route path="/team" component={Team} />
            <Route path="/contact" component={Contact} />
            <Route path="/documents" component={Documents} />


          <Footer />
        </div>
      );
    }
  }

export default App;
```

I would like to know how can I render all the other classes so that they display as their own pages when the header links are clicked, like in a normal website

Comment: To rectify the first line: It only displays the Header and Footer components

Comment: please go through react router nav link concepts

Answer (score 0):

You can create links to these pages using Link:

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
<Link to="/">Home</Link>
<Link to="/about">About</Link>
<Link to="/projects">Projects</Link>
...
```

The way I do it is to have a NavBar component with all the Links and an AppRoutes component with all the routes like this:

```
const App = () => {
    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
                <NavBar />
                <AppRoutes />
        </BrowserRouter>
    );
}
```

Comment: The links are in a separate component

Comment: import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

class Header extends Component {

                  <div className={'nav-right nav-menu '+menuActive}>
                    <Link to="/" className="nav-item r-item">Home</Link>
                    <Link to="/about" className="nav-item r-item">About</Link>
                    <Link to="/projects" className="nav-item r-item">Projects</Link>
                  </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }

export default Header;

Comment: Don't forget that your App should be rendered inside a <BrowserRouter>

Comment: The App is rendered inside a <BrowserRouter> in an index.js file. The navigation works locally, but I run into these problems after build for some reason.

Comment: Which problem do you run into?

Comment: In the build 1) it does not display the components which should be the web page content (only displays header and footer). 2) The header links do not navigate to the different pages

Comment: When you hover your Header links, do you see the correct URL?

Comment: Yes. Like I said, everything works fine under production, these problems occur in the build

Answer (score 0):

I have finally found a solution:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Header from './components/Header/Header';
import Footer from './components/Footer/Footer';
import Home from './components/Home/Home';
import About from './components/About/About';
import Team from './components/Team/Team';
import Projects from './components/Projects/Projects';
import Contact from './components/Contact/Contact';
import Documents from './components/Documents/Documents';
import FAQ from './components/FAQ/FAQ';
import { HashRouter as Router, Route, Link, Switch, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {

      return (
        <Router>
            <div className="App">
              <Header />
              <Switch>
                <Route exact={true} path="/" component={Home} />
                <Route exact path="/about" component={About} />
                <Route exact path="/projects" component={Projects} />
                <Route exact path="/team" component={Team} />
                <Route exact path="/contact" component={Contact} />
                <Route exact path="/documents" component={Documents} />
              </Switch>
              <Footer />
            </div>
        </Router>
      );
    }

export default App;
```

What I had to do was nest the routes inside Route and Switch, and then change the  import to HashRouter, this was the reason the components were not loading.